# Отмена ajax запроса с помощью abort()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Нашёл в интернете как можно отменить выполнение ajax запроса при необходимости. И вот мне нужно отменить его если поле формы пустое и нечего не передаётся. Вот мой код:

```
$('#btnConfirm').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#pass').css('display') == 'none') {
            AjaxPassRecovery("/Authorization/FindUserAccount", Success)
        }
    });

function AjaxPassRecovery(url, callback) {
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                var mail = $('#txtMail').val();
                if (mail === '')
                    xhr.abort();
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                "Email": $('#txtMail').val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                callback(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                swal({
                    title: xhr.responseText,
                    type: "warning"
                });
            }
        });
    }

function Success(result) {
        if (result > 0) {
            $('#txtMail').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            $('#pass').slideDown();
        }
    }
```

Я привязываю к кнопке выполнение функции с ajax запросом и в нём колбеком вызываю функцию success. И вот как в примере нашёл в переменную xhr записываю ajax запрос. И в событии до отправки ajax запроса проверяю если поле пустое то отменить выполнение запроса. Но вылетает ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подумал что дело в области видимости и объявил переменную xhr глобально на этой странице, но ошибка та же самая. В чём дело? Что я делаю не так? То что я увидел в примерах в интернете выглядит примерно так же.

Comment: Зачем такие сложности? Разве не легче просто не запускать функцию `AjaxPassRecovery`, если поле не пустое? Тем более, что отмена `ajax` **НЕ** останавливает обработку запроса на сервере.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko отменяет, уже нашёл способ как правильно отменить с помощью abort

Comment: Нет, не отменяет. Работа на бакенде будет продолжаться.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я это уже попробовал, работа до сервера даже не доходит, я до отправки запроса отменяю его, возможно она продолжается если она уже дошла до сервера. А в моём случае всё отрабатывает идеально.

Comment: Аборт это грех, одумайся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) { // сюда добавить xhr 
                var mail = $('#txtMail').val();
                if (mail === '')
                    xhr.abort();
            },
```

Comment: holden321, да именно так уже и сделал и даже не нужно присваивать в переменную сам ajax запрос, просто в функцию передать.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том что на момент вызова функции `beforeSend` `xhr = undefined`, поэтому вместо того чтобы отменять запрос лучше его вообще не отправлять.

```
function AjaxPassRecovery(url, callback) {
    var mail = $('#txtMail').val();
    if (mail === '') return;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {
            Email: mail
        },
        success: function (result) {
            callback(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            swal({
                title: xhr.responseText,
                type: 'warning'
            });
        }
    });
}
```